# Double integral over $f(x,y) = y^2x+x^3$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the integral $$\int_D f \ dx \ dy$$ where $f : D\to \mathbb{R}, f(x,y) = y^2x+x^3$ and $D= \{(x,y) \mid \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leqslant 5, y >0\}$

Converting to polar coordinates I got $f(r,\theta) = r^3\cos(\theta)$ and $D = \{(r,\theta) \mid 0 \leqslant r \leqslant 5, 0\leqslant \theta \leqslant 2\pi \} $ So the integral would become $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{5} r^4\cos(\theta) \ dr \ d\theta = \int _0^{2\pi }\cos \left(θ\right)\cdot \:625 \ d\theta = 0.$$

I guess I have a mistake here since isn't this just a cone whose projection on to the $xy$ plane is a circle of radius $5$ and the area shouldn't evaluate to zero?

Comment: Your $D$ i polar coordinates is the whole circle in $\theta$. How do you treat the constraint $y>0$?

Comment: Ah I see, it should be $\theta \in [0, \pi]?$

Comment: Another comment: area of $D$ is not zero, but it does not mean that the integral must be non-zero. Integral is a weighted area (signed area), can easily be zero or even negative sometimes.

Comment: It seems that even with $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ the integral equals zero?

Comment: An integral is *not* an area. It's a sum -- and sums can be $0.$

Comment: Zero is the [correct value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947086/computing-a-double-integral-over-d-x-y-in-mathbfr2-sqrtx2y2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that $f(x,y) = y^2x+x^3$ is an odd function with respect to $x$ which means

$f(-x,y) = y^2(-x) + (-x)^3 = - (y^2x+x^3) = - f(x, y)$

So if you integrate over a region which is symmetric to $y-$axis, integral over negative values of $x$ will cancel out integral over positive values of $x$ and that is correct answer. Here you are integrating it over a circle $(-5 \leq x \leq 5, x^2 + y^2 = 25)$ which is symmetric to $y-$ axis.

If you were given the condition $x \geq 0$, the integral would not be zero as the function is even wrt $y$.

I hope this clarifies.